# How to compare words in two lists according to same order in python?(I have def a function)

Tags: python

Recently, I def a function which can compare two words in each wordlist. However, I also found some problems here.

```
def printcorrectletters():
    x=0
    for letters in correctanswer:
        for letters2 in userinput:
            if letters == letters2:
                x = x+1
            break         
return x
```

In this function, if the correctanswer='HUNTING', and I input 'GHUNTIN', it will show 6 letters are correct. However, I want it compare words' letters 1 by 1. So, it should march 0. For example, 'H' will match first letter of userinput.. and so on.

I also think another function which can solve it by using 'zip'. However, our TA ask me to finish it without things like 'zip'.

Comment: So `GHUNTIN` should match 0 of 6?

Comment: GHUNTIN should match 0 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the strings are different lengths, you want to compare each letter of the shorter string:

```
shortest_length = min(len(correctanswer), len(userinput))
```

[**`min`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) just gives you the minimum of two or more values. You could code it yourself as:

```
def min(a, b):
    return a if a < b else b
```

You can index a character in a string, using `[index]`:

```
>>> 'Guanfong'[3]
n
```

So you can loop over all the letter indices:

```
correct = 0
for index in range(shortest_length):
    if correctanswer[index] == userinput[index]:
        correct += 1
```

If you did use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [**`sum`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
correct = sum(1 for (correct_char, user_char) in zip(correctanswer, userinput)
              if correct_char == user_char)
```

Python provides great facilities for simplifying ideas and for communicating with the computer *and programmers* (including yourself, tomorrow).

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in the example (just waking up). `[3]` should return the 4th character `n`.

Comment: Haha ,that's totally Ok! Thank you very much! I am working on your example. You really help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Without [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) you can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to loop over elements of correctanswer , and get index and element at the same time. Example -

```
def printcorrectletters():
    x=0
    for i, letter in enumerate(correctanswer):
        if i < len(userinput) and letter == userinput[i]:
            x = x+1      
    return x
```

Or if even `enumerate()` is not allowed, simply use `range()` loop till `len(correctanswer)` and get elements from each index.